# python unable to get ip address using socket connection with broadcast

Tags: python, sockets, solaris

Am trying to get IP address of the server using below method on Linux,

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan  9 2013, 01:38:41)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
>>> s.connect(('<broadcast>', 0))
>>> s.getsockname()[0]
'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
>>>
```

but when I tried the same method on Solaris system with Python 2.6.4 its not working and getting error as below,

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Apr 20 2011, 20:04:12) [C] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
>>> s.connect(('<broadcast>', 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 126] Cannot assign requested address
>>>
```

So would like to understand that whether the functionality is getting differ based on OS flavor for this python module. In my setup the IP is not registered with any hostname so I can't reply on the hostname to get the details, for this purpose I have to use this socket connection method to get the IP address.

**Update :**

My intention is to get the IP address of the server without using /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score -1):

try using python 3 maybe  that will solve it